# Express middleware with parameters messes other routes

Tags: node.js, express

the problem is when i define a middleware on a path with parameters the middleware also applies on other routes that dont have the param

i have this code:

app.use('/group/:groupId', groupmiddleware)

// This route should go through the groupMiddleware
app.get('/groups/:groupId/another', (req, res) => {});

// Route that should not go through the groupMiddleware
app.get('/groups/all', (req, res) => {});

now when I send a request to /groups/all it goes through the middleware when it shouldn't
any advice or way to fix it would be appreciated.
I am using express 4.18

Comment: Please use punctuation and format your code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the way you have defined the routes. You can define the middleware like this, so it will get used on that particular route.

Suppose if you want to use that middleware on this route only, then do this:

```
app.get('/groups/:groupId/another', [groupmiddleware], (req, res) => {})
```

So `groupmiddleware` will only get used on this route.

Also sequence of routes also depends on express, define the routes in this sequence:

```
app.get('/groups/all', (req, res) => {})
app.get('/groups/:groupId', (req, res) => {})
app.get('/groups/:groupId/another', (req, res) => {})
```

Comment: i know that the order matters but i cant change it because i have many routers and changing it  would make it harder to understand and harder to add more routes also putting the middleware for each route that needs it is good but it is also easier for new people to make mistakes with forgetting to add it and such 
which is why im searching for a way to apply it to a path with params

Comment: @yonheta you can whitelist that particular path in the `groupmiddleware`. So inside that middleware, you can define if route is `groups/all` then bypass the middleware check.